# Django Query Filter Null

Tags: mysql, django, django-views

This is my query

```
count = Attend.objects.filter(date = NULL).count()
```

This gives me an enter date in correct format error. I am trying to filter for date set as null.

what do i do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
count = Attend.objects.filter(date__isnull = True).count()
```